# pass dag_run.conf to TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have 2 dags: dagA and dagB.

dagB takes a trigger parameter in the format of: {"key": ["value"]}

dagA is a wrapper DAG that calls dagB. I'm not sure how to pass the dag_run.conf to dabB in the conf option.

```
    trigger_dagB = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dagB',
        trigger_dag_id='dagB',
        execution_date='{{ ds }}',
        conf={"key": {{ dag_run.conf['key'] }}},
        reset_dag_run=True,
        wait_for_completion=True,
        poke_interval=60
    )
```

This will pass {'key': "['value']"} to dagB, and it failed because the format is wrong.
It should be {"key": ["value"]}

also tried, but same result:

```
conf='{{ dag_run.conf }}',
```

Comment: does your DAG defined with "render_template_as_native_obj=True" ?

Comment: @ozs hmm. this might be exactly what I need. but I got this error after adding this into the DAG options: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'render_template_as_native_obj'. my airflow version is 2.0.2

Comment: Just found that render_template_as_native_obj was introduced in 2.1.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: It fails because in the DAG B you expect having an array as value ?

Comment: it's because of the quote. should be {"key": ["value"]}, but it passed as {'key': "['value']"}